# Calculate distance between two NON USA postal codes or adresses in BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distance

First of all, I was looking into it but all the answers use public USA data with the zip codes `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.zipcode_area` so for this case is not usefull.

So I have two zip codes that is **NOT IN THE USA AREA**, also i have the full adresses and I just wondering how to calculate the distance between them in meters if possible or in any other measure.

Also would work if we can extract the latitude and longitude points of it but again dont know how to do it for a **NON USA** location.

Can someone have an idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your address for a single country? Have you looked into resources to see if there's a lat/long reference for that country?

Comment: That depends on the country - you'll need to search online for zipcode database for your country, and upload it to your project. Most countries publish this data on the web in a suitable format. You can then create your own version of zipcode_area for your country.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no public dataset currently for other countries at the moment.

Also for distance BigQuery as a Geography function [ST_DISTANCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_distance)

> Returns the shortest distance in meters between two non-empty
> GEOGRAPHYs.

```
ST_DISTANCE(geography_1, geography_2[, use_spheroid])
```